# Tile to carpet transition

Tags: tile, carpet, gap

I will be removing my old carpet and getting a new one. I am not sure the height of the carpet yet. But i need to finish installing door jambs and I think I'll need to leave at-least 3/8 gap for the carpet to be tucked in, correct (orange line)? Or just put door jamb all the way to the sub floor (blue line)?

What i am concerned about is the gap between the tile schluter and the carpet. As it stands, it is about 1 inch gap now between the sub floor and the schluter. If carpet is 1/2 inch in height, there would be a visible gap between them. Can carpet installer maybe build some sort of buildup to raise the carpet at the and or i will be stuck with a gap there?

Any advise welcome.

[image: tile to carpet]

Answer (score 2):

The way I addressed this  issue was with a wide shim under  the carpet that brought the floor height up gradually over about 12 inches I made my own but you can buy them 
look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4V8C7I8qtK8) video to see how they work

You can purchase kits of various sizes to fit your needs [here](http://www.tools4flooring.com/carpet-shims.html)

( I do not have any affiliation with the companies featured in this answer)

Comment: So i had the carpet installed yesterday. Installer added what looked like a cedar siding shingle to gradually add the incline. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the door jambs up the 3/8" - 1/2", less cutting in for them to do, they will love you for it.

My suggestion for the difference in height is something the tile guy should have addressed- not with a Schluter molding...at least not like that. On to what could have been done, back in the day a marble threshold was set there. It could have been set on the  same base the tile was set on, but the prep had to be there.

For a quick simple fix a piece of stained wood set to the floor 1" tall will cover the space that offends thee before the carpet goes in.

Comment: Back in your day is still in effect in this day, at least for me - Lowes and the Depot still stock marble thresholds (granite, too, some days) and I still use them. I'd drop in a form board (removable, of course) at the right distance (ripping up the tack strip first) and plunk in enough mortar or thinset to set a threshold in there. If I could remove that silly trim piece without damaging the tile, I'd take it out as well. I suppose you could work with the darn thing and use a wood threshold if you can't remove it without tile damage.

Comment: @Ecnerwal ,  Yes I used the term a little loosely. On another note, do you see the same thing I see? The schluter trim that is there has a projection like it is a "T" molding? It is a stretch, but could not the tack strip be pulled out and pack enough thinset into the recess to grip a small strip of tile tucked under the T strip to hide the cut edge and rest it on the subfloor, if only as a temporary support so to speak until the thinset bonds the tile to the existing setting bed. Not the best idea, but at least the colors will be right. Almost vertical, with a slight ramp.

Comment: @Jack it is not a "T" schluter. i realized picture doesnt show it, but it is sloped down.

Comment: That's a bummer, you could still add a marble threshold after the door is set and hope for the best...  Set a small piece of tarpaper and screw a piece of wire lath before thinsetting the marble, use white thinset